# I am having trouble switching items in a menu

Tags: java, menu, awt, itemlistener

So I have Menu that invokes an itemlistener on each item as so.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class GuessWindow extends Frame implements Constants
    {
     MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
     GuesstimateGraph anApp;
     GuessDoc guess;
     ScrollPane drawArea = null;
     int addType;

     CheckboxMenuItem Yaxis = new CheckboxMenuItem("Y-axis", DEFAULT_TYPE==YAXIS);
     CheckboxMenuItem Xaxis = new CheckboxMenuItem("X-axis", DEFAULT_TYPE==XAXIS);
     CheckboxMenuItem Zaxis = new CheckboxMenuItem("Z-axis", DEFAULT_TYPE==ZAXIS);
     CheckboxMenuItem Yaxislabel = new CheckboxMenuItem("Y label", DEFAULT_TYPE==YLABEL);
     CheckboxMenuItem Xaxislabel = new CheckboxMenuItem("X label", DEFAULT_TYPE==XLABEL);
     CheckboxMenuItem Zaxislabel = new CheckboxMenuItem("Z label", DEFAULT_TYPE==ZLABEL);
     CheckboxMenuItem axisbreak = new CheckboxMenuItem("Break", DEFAULT_TYPE==BREAK);

     CheckboxMenuItem select = new CheckboxMenuItem("Select", DEFAULT_TYPE==SELECT);
     CheckboxMenuItem delete = new CheckboxMenuItem("Delete", DEFAULT_TYPE==DELETE);
     CheckboxMenuItem move = new CheckboxMenuItem("Move", DEFAULT_TYPE==MOVE);
     //make panel with file edit and import picture to add x,y,z axis and 2 labels on each and line breaks
     public GuessWindow(String title, GuesstimateGraph anApp)
     {
      this.anApp = anApp;
      setMenuBar(menuBar);

      Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");

      MenuItem item;
      fileMenu.add(item = new MenuItem("New", new MenuShortcut('N')));
      fileMenu.add(item = new MenuItem("Open", new MenuShortcut('O')));
      fileMenu.add(item = new MenuItem("Close", new MenuShortcut('C')));
      fileMenu.addSeparator();
      fileMenu.addSeparator();
      fileMenu.add(item = new MenuItem("Save", new MenuShortcut('S')));
      fileMenu.add(item = new MenuItem("Save as..."));
      fileMenu.addSeparator();
      fileMenu.add(item = new MenuItem("Print", new MenuShortcut('P')));
      MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit", new MenuShortcut('a'));
      fileMenu.add(exit);
      exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });

      Menu addMenu = new Menu("Add");

      Yaxis.addItemListener(new AxisCommand(YAXIS, guess));
      Xaxis.addItemListener(new AxisCommand(XAXIS, guess));
      Zaxis.addItemListener(new AxisCommand(ZAXIS, guess));
      Yaxislabel.addItemListener(new AxisCommand(YLABEL, guess));
      Xaxislabel.addItemListener(new AxisCommand(XLABEL, guess));
      Zaxislabel.addItemListener(new AxisCommand(ZLABEL, guess));
      axisbreak.addItemListener(new AxisCommand(BREAK, guess));

      addMenu.add(Yaxis);
      addMenu.add(Xaxis);
      addMenu.add(Zaxis);
      addMenu.add(Yaxislabel);
      addMenu.add(Xaxislabel);
      addMenu.add(Zaxislabel);
      addMenu.add(axisbreak);

      Menu editMenu = new Menu("Edit");
      editMenu.add(select);
      editMenu.add(delete);
      editMenu.add(move);

      addMenu.add(editMenu);

      Menu ImportMenu = new Menu("Import");

      ImportMenu.add(item = new MenuItem("Select Pic"));
      ImportMenu.add(item = new MenuItem("Resize"));
      ImportMenu.add(item = new MenuItem("Crop"));

      //if further developed add a draw menu to point out specific features

      menuBar.add(fileMenu);
      menuBar.add(addMenu);
      menuBar.add(ImportMenu);





    }

    public void setaddcheck(int addType)
    {
     Yaxis.setState(YAXIS==addType);
     Xaxis.setState(XAXIS==addType);
     Zaxis.setState(ZAXIS==addType);
     Yaxislabel.setState(YLABEL==addType);
     Xaxislabel.setState(XLABEL==addType);
     Zaxislabel.setState(ZLABEL==addType);
     axisbreak.setState(BREAK==addType);
    }

    public void seteditcheck(int editType)
    {
     select.setState(SELECT==editType);
     delete.setState(DELETE==editType);
     move.setState(MOVE==editType);
    }

    public void addView(GuessView view)
    {
     drawArea = new ScrollPane();
     drawArea.add(view);
     add(drawArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    }
```

The ItemListener Code looks like this

```
    import java.awt.event.*;

    class AxisCommand implements ItemListener, Constants
    {
     int addTypeid;
     GuessDoc guess;

     public AxisCommand(int addTypeid, GuessDoc guess)
     {
      this.addTypeid = addTypeid;
      this.guess = guess;
     }

     public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
     {
      guess.setType(addTypeid);
     }

    }
```

The problem at the moment is actually here the System says that *guess.setType(addTypeid);* has a null pointer exception. GuessDoc.setType(int id) reads like this

```
    int addType;

    public void setType(int addType)
    {
     this.addType = addType;
     window.setaddcheck(addType);
    }
```

The constants are all the ints listed i.e. YAXIS, XAXIS, YLABEL, etc.  If you think something is missing, which I have left a lot out for space sakes, ask. Thanks, in advance.  Like I said when I click an item in the list other than the default value the System reads null pointer exception and I do not know why.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you assign a GuessDoc object for your guess variable in your first class? I don't see that you ever do this, much less do it before creating your ItemListeners. Thus you are passing nulls as the second parameter of your ItemListeners.

Recommendations:

- don't do this. Don't create your ItemListeners before all parameter objects have been fully realized.
- As an aside, I strongly suggest that you avoid using AWT and prefer use of Swing GUI's.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> I assign it in the very beginning with all of the other variables as GuessDoc guess; I think it is on line 8. I don't know what your first suggestion means.

Please show me which line you mean.  I see this:

```
GuessDoc guess;
```

Please understand that is ***not*** an assignment but just a variable declaration, and is the exact same as this:

```
GuessDoc guess = null;
```

I don't see where you're creating a new GuessDoc object **anywhere**. If you're going to assign a value to the variable then it has to be done like so:

```
GuessDoc guess = new GuessDoc();
```

or

```
    GuessDoc guess;
    guess = new GuessDoc();
```

Consider reading through the first few chapters of a decent intro to Java text book such as Head First Java as it will help you to get you up to speed with Java quickly. I know because it sure helped me.

---

**Edit 2**
You state in comment:

> That's not the problem, but ok.

Yes it is. Your problem is that you're getting a NPE on this line:

```
guess.setType(addTypeid);
```

which means that `guess` is null. I'm trying to show you why it's null -- because when you call this constructor:

```
 public AxisCommand(int addTypeid, GuessDoc guess)
 {
  this.addTypeid = addTypeid;
  this.guess = guess;
 }
```

here:

```
Yaxis.addItemListener(new AxisCommand(YAXIS, guess));
```

you're passing in a null value for guess since guess is never initialized with in your main program before making the call above.

I'm not saying that this is the only problem with your code, since there are other issues that will eventually need to be addressed, but again, the issues I've described above are the **only** reason that your program is throwing a NullPointerException where you describe it to be happening.

Comment: I assign it in the very beginning with all of the other variables as GuessDoc guess; I think it is on line 8. I don't know what your first suggestion means.

Comment: That's not the problem, but ok.

Comment: @user3277602: please see edit 2. I can't force you to believe what I'm saying, but trust me, what I tell you is true and does explain your NPE error. But hey, it's your program, so best of luck to you.

Comment: Thank you I added guess = new GuessDoc(anApp);, which is another class, still nothing. So that really isn't the problem

Comment: @user3277602: You state, `"Thank you I added guess = new GuessDoc(anApp);, which is another class, still nothing. So that really isn't the problem"` -- what do you  mean "still nothing"? Are you still getting the NPE? If so, is it being thrown on the same line? Or is something else happening. Please help us understand your problem better by communicating your problem as completely as possible.

Comment: @user3277602: and I see that you've asked 5 questions on this site, have received answers to all your questions, and yet have not accepted a single answer to any of your questions. Why? That's not quite fair to the folks trying to help you, you know.

Comment: Yeah NPE, and yeah I could probably answer some other people's questions. I don't think I have because I view myself as learning still at the moment, but I could probably answer some questions.

Comment: @user3277602: again are you getting the exact **same** NPE on the same line? And I'm not asking you to answer questions, but rather to accept the best answer in each of your 4 previous questions. Please read up in the help section on how to accept answers. You thank the **volunteers** here by accepting the best answer and up-voting all helpful answers.

Comment: Oh no, on most of my questions I answer them myself or they go unanswered. Also yes the same NPE occurs on a different line because I added 2 lines for the proper assignment you suggested.

Comment: @user3277602: `"Oh no, on most of my questions I answer them myself or they go unanswered."` -- You've gotten decent answers on all 4, but I'm probably wasting my breath. Good luck.